# How i can add bookmarks in files or Pantheon Files 0.1

Tags: files, bookmarks, pantheon

I installed this software but I can't find the option to add bookmarks, or add to my favorite places.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the folder you want and press `Ctrl+D`and voilà! the bookmarks shows!

Answer (score 1):

I have a little trick for this, install or open (already installed in elementary os luna) nautilus and add your bookmarks, then close and open phantheon files and voilà! the bookmarks shows!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dragging it on the sidebar, or stuff like this? (Also, all menus, including right-click menu?)

Comment: I tried that and not working

Comment: :( 

Ask here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/104613975513761463450 or here: http://master.elementaryos.org/support/live or here: master.elementaryos.org/developer/chat